# Fill array with vectors in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am rather new to c++ and would like to achieve the following:

```
 ttgl::vec3f positions[] = {
    ttgl::vec3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f),
    ttgl::vec3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f),
    ttgl::vec3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f),
    ttgl::vec3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f),
    ttgl::vec3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f),
    ttgl::vec3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f),

};
```

The problem is, that I don't know the values and have to fill this array dynamically.

I try to achieve it with the following function:

```
void getCirclePositions(GLfloat radius, GLint sides) {
ttgl::vec3f center = ttgl::vec3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
GLfloat angle = (2.0f * M_PI) / sides;
ttgl::vec3f positions[100];
positions[0] = center;


for (int i = 1; i <= sides; i++) {
    GLfloat angleFan = angle * (i + 1);
    GLfloat xCoordinate = radius * cos(angleFan);
    GLfloat yCoordinate = radius * sin(angleFan);
    ttgl::vec3f point = ttgl::vec3f(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, 0.0f);
    positions[i] = point;


}
return positions;
};
```

This leads to the following error:

```
Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'positions' was 
corrupted.
```

How could I insert the values correctly?

**EDIT**

The function is called as follows:

```
 getCirclePositions(1.0f, 100);
```

I edited the code accordingly and the error is solved. Thanks for that.

```
void getCirclePositions(GLfloat radius, GLint sides) {
ttgl::vec3f center = ttgl::vec3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
GLfloat angle = (2.0f * M_PI) / sides;
ttgl::vec3f positions[100];
positions[0] = center;


for (int i = 1; i < sides; i++) {
    GLfloat angleFan = angle * (i + 1);
    GLfloat xCoordinate = radius * cos(angleFan);
    GLfloat yCoordinate = radius * sin(angleFan);
    ttgl::vec3f point = ttgl::vec3f(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, 0.0f);
    positions[i] = point;


}
for (int i = 0; i >sides; i++) {
    std::cout << positions[i];
}
```

};

How can I print this array?

Comment: Use `std::vector<ttgl::vec3f>` and `push_back` (or `emplace_back`) the values?

Comment: Is `sides` >= 100?

Comment: It appears you're using one-based indexing, but C++ arrays use zero-based indexing.

Comment: [MCVE] plz.....

Comment: @FredLarson `positions[0]` is assigned before the loop at `positions[0] = center;`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Fair enough. But in `for (int i = 1; i <= sides; i++)`, if `sides == 100`, it's going off the end of the array.

Comment: @FredLarson That's true, but we don't know what `sides` is. The same would be true for `i < sides` though with sides being limited to less than 101. Since it seems like OP is storing both the center of a circle and the position of each vertex used to draw it in the same array, it's expected that `positions` would need `n+1` elements to draw a circle composed of `n` lines (`n` lines plus the center). In that case, the `for` loop to iterate over the vertex positions would be from `1` to `n` inclusively rather than the traditional `0` to `n-1` inclusively.

Comment: What it all boils down to is this question cannot be answered without a [mcve], which is why I've voted to close.